# Apache MINA SFTP - limit the directory structure that the user sees

Tags: java, authorization, sshd, mina

Am using Apache MINA SSHD to build my own custom SFTP Server.

I want to limit the file system my user sees. I just want them to see the directory structure under /aa/bb/cc

I do not want them to be able to see or navigate any other folder.

And from the directories under /aa/bb/cc, a user will have read access to some directories and write access to only a selected few. How do I achive this ?

Answer (score 2):

The FileSystemView has been introduced for that very purpose. If you're using version `0.14.0`, the following will work:

```
 sshServer.setFileSystemFactory(new VirtualFileSystemFactory(new File("admin").getAbsolutePath()));
```

I have also almost got a working example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441969/configure-multiple-user-home-directories). I just have to figure out how to set the home directory dynamically.