# Apache MINA SFTP Example

Tags: java, sftp, sshd, apache-mina

I'm trying to set up an SFTP server with multiple users that each have their own home directory.

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389249/how-to-set-root-directory-in-apache-mina-sshd-server-in-java) which explained how to set a virtual directory for a single user but I'm not sure how to have multiple users each with their own home directory.

Can someone please tell me how to go about this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally got it working. Here is a working example:

**pom.xml**

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
    <artifactId>sshd-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Test.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.sshd.SshServer;
import org.apache.sshd.common.NamedFactory;
import org.apache.sshd.common.file.virtualfs.VirtualFileSystemFactory;
import org.apache.sshd.server.Command;
import org.apache.sshd.server.PasswordAuthenticator;
import org.apache.sshd.server.UserAuth;
import org.apache.sshd.server.auth.UserAuthPassword;
import org.apache.sshd.server.command.ScpCommandFactory;
import org.apache.sshd.server.keyprovider.SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider;
import org.apache.sshd.server.session.ServerSession;
import org.apache.sshd.server.sftp.SftpSubsystem;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo fuser -k " + "2222" + "/tcp");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        File TEST = new File("test");
        File ADMIN = new File("admin");
        File ERROR = new File("error");

        TEST.mkdirs();
        ADMIN.mkdirs();
        ERROR.mkdirs();

        SshServer sshServer = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
        sshServer.setFileSystemFactory(new VirtualFileSystemFactory(ERROR.getAbsolutePath()));
        sshServer.setPort(2222);
        sshServer.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider(new File("my.pem").getAbsolutePath()));
        sshServer.setCommandFactory(new ScpCommandFactory());
        List<NamedFactory<UserAuth>> userAuthFactories = new ArrayList<>();
        userAuthFactories.add(new UserAuthPassword.Factory());
        sshServer.setUserAuthFactories(userAuthFactories);
        sshServer.setPasswordAuthenticator(new PasswordAuthenticator() {
            @Override
            public boolean authenticate(String username, String password, ServerSession session) {
                if ((username.equals("test")) && (password.equals("test"))) {
                    sshServer.setFileSystemFactory(new VirtualFileSystemFactory(TEST.getAbsolutePath()));
                    return true;
                }
                if ((username.equals("admin")) && (password.equals("admin"))) {
                    sshServer.setFileSystemFactory(new VirtualFileSystemFactory(ADMIN.getAbsolutePath()));
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        List<NamedFactory<Command>> namedFactoryList = new ArrayList<>();
        namedFactoryList.add(new SftpSubsystem.Factory());
        sshServer.setSubsystemFactories(namedFactoryList);
        try {
            sshServer.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CarrierSFTPServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Only caveat with this is that it may potentially have issues with concurrent users. I'm not sure how to resolve this though.

Comment: It would be great if there was a more up to date version of the above.

Comment: Hi, `VirtualFileSystemFactory` has a `setUserHomeDir` method where you can specify a home directory by user. Then FileSystemFactory will be able to handle many users.

Comment: :( Gives me a build issue locally: `Cannot resolve symbol 'CarrierSFTPServer'`

Answer (score 3):

Updated version of above (as of 1.4.0 of sshd-core). Note that I did not specify a file for the host key provider since mine was for a Junit integration test.

```
List<NamedFactory<UserAuth>> userAuthFactories = new ArrayList<NamedFactory<UserAuth>>();
userAuthFactories.add(new UserAuthPasswordFactory());

List<NamedFactory<Command>> sftpCommandFactory = new ArrayList<NamedFactory<Command>>();
sftpCommandFactory.add(new SftpSubsystemFactory());

SshServer sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
sshd.setPort(22);
sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider());
sshd.setUserAuthFactories(userAuthFactories);
sshd.setCommandFactory(new ScpCommandFactory());
sshd.setSubsystemFactories(sftpCommandFactory);
sshd.setPasswordAuthenticator(new PasswordAuthenticator() {
  @Override
  public boolean authenticate(String username, String password, ServerSession session) {
    if ((username.equals("admin")) && (password.equals("admin"))) {
      sshd.setFileSystemFactory(new VirtualFileSystemFactory(new File("C:\\devl").toPath()));
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
});

sshd.start();
```

Comment: Copy-pasting this into the version 0.14.0 code, there are compile errors, and I can't seem to find some of the referenced classes, like  UserAuthPasswordFactory and SftpSubsystemFactory. I guess other imports are required?

Answer (score 1):

For version 2.8.0 (dependency GAV: `org.apache.sshd:sshd-sftp:2.8.0`) this file provided a great resource for me:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/main/basic/sftp/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/sftp/EmbeddedSftpServer.java

Excerpt because the link may break:

```
// ...

import org.apache.sshd.common.file.virtualfs.VirtualFileSystemFactory;
import org.apache.sshd.server.SshServer;
import org.apache.sshd.server.keyprovider.SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider;
import org.apache.sshd.sftp.server.SftpSubsystemFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.context.SmartLifecycle;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory;
import org.springframework.util.Base64Utils;
import org.springframework.util.StreamUtils;
        
public class EmbeddedSftpServer implements InitializingBean, SmartLifecycle { 

    // ...

    private DefaultSftpSessionFactory defaultSftpSessionFactory;

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void setDefaultSftpSessionFactory(DefaultSftpSessionFactory defaultSftpSessionFactory) {
        this.defaultSftpSessionFactory = defaultSftpSessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        final PublicKey allowedKey = decodePublicKey();
        this.server.setPublickeyAuthenticator((username, key, session) -> key.equals(allowedKey));
        this.server.setPort(this.port);
        this.server.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider(new File("hostkey.ser").toPath()));
        server.setSubsystemFactories(Collections.singletonList(new SftpSubsystemFactory()));
        final String pathname = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + File.separator + "sftptest" + File.separator;
        new File(pathname).mkdirs();
        server.setFileSystemFactory(new VirtualFileSystemFactory(Paths.get(pathname)));
    }

// ...
```

I usually leave the port unspecified, it uses a random port then, it seems.